# Make enemies attack each other

Tags: garrys-mod

Gmod noob here trying to have some fun with the game. What I thought might be fun would be to load up koth_harvest_final and simulate a battle between rebels and combine from HL2, dropping in the occasional antlion or zombie to liven things up. However, the two factions don't do anything. I spawn them in on opposite sides of the map with thinking disabled, and then run these commands:

```
ent_fire npc_citizen startpatrolling
ent_fire npc_combine_s startpatrolling
```

and then turn AI back on (through the NPC menu).

As you might imagine, this starts the two factions wandering around. However, they take forever to find each other (if they manage it at all) and then the gunfights are short and sporadic - one member of one faction will kill an enemy, and then just start wandering around again. Is there any way to make the two factions actively seek each other out and begin fighting?

Comment: Well for a start, that command isn't going to work. It is specifically made for "patrolling". And the kind of patrolling I'm talking about, is wandering around doing absolutely nothing. It's not made for seeking.